# SonarQube Returning Bad Gateway Error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sonarqube, webserver, caddy

I'm trying to serve SonarQube using Caddy. I'm able to view the site, but it returns 502 Bad Gateway. The service appears to be up and running. Also curling locally is rejected.

#### curl

```
curl -I 0.0.0.0:9000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 9000: Connection refused
```

#### sonar.properties

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# WEB SERVER
# Web server is executed in a dedicated Java process. By default heap size is 512Mb.
# Use the following property to customize JVM options.
#    Recommendations:
#
#    The HotSpot Server VM is recommended. The property -server should be added if server mode
#    is not enabled by default on your environment:
#    http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html
#
#    Startup can be long if entropy source is short of entropy. Adding
#    -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom is an option to resolve the problem.
#    See https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo/FasterStartUp#Entropy_Source
#
#sonar.web.javaOpts=-Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

# Same as previous property, but allows to not repeat all other settings like -Xmx
#sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts=

# Binding IP address. For servers with more than one IP address, this property specifies which
# address will be used for listening on the specified ports.
# By default, ports will be used on all IP addresses associated with the server.
#sonar.web.host=0.0.0.0

# Web context. When set, it must start with forward slash (for example /sonarqube).
# The default value is root context (empty value).
#sonar.web.context=
# TCP port for incoming HTTP connections. Default value is 9000.
#sonar.web.port=9000
sonar.web.https.port=8999
```

#### Caddyfile

```
https://....com {
  tls self_signed
  gzip
  proxy /  0.0.0.0:9000
}

http://....com {
  tls off
  gzip
  proxy / 127.0.0.1:9000
}
```

Comment: Please post your Caddyfile.

Comment: @JeremiahMegel I've added above

Comment: Can you post your web.log file to see on which port SonarQube is listening ? (please note that sonar.web.https.port is no more used)

Comment: @EricHartmann I've posted the log here https://gist.github.com/atbyrd/3baf15f0df899e178d365c5babd857b2

Comment: @AntarrByrd, according to your log files, SonarQube is unable to connect to your database. You should check that your database configuration in sonar.properties are correct (username, password, jdbc URL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0.0.0.0` is not a routable address. It is used by servers as a ["meta-address"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) to specify that it should listen on all available addresses as opposed to just one. So a server can **listen on** `0.0.0.0`, but a client cannot **make requests to** `0.0.0.0`. Your Caddyfile should look like this:

```
https://....com {
  tls self_signed
  gzip
  proxy / 127.0.0.1:9000
}

http://....com {
  tls off
  gzip
  proxy / 127.0.0.1:9000
}
```

And local cURL requests should look like this: `curl 127.0.0.1:9000`

Comment: I still get the same behavior.